# Mapping Capslock to Esc and Capslock & C to a function in Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to configure autohotkey in the following way:

```
Capslock::Esc

Capslock & C::
Run, www.stackoverflow.com
return
```

So if I just press `Capslock` it treated like if I would have pressed `Esc`. If I on the other hand press both `Capslock` and `c`, it call the function that opens the browser with `www.stackoverflow.com`.

At the moment the remapped seems to break when I have the other function in the script. When I press capslock now it toggles it for a short time, so the key alone does effectively nothing. I don't get my `Esc`.

Pressing capslocks + A on the other hand activates capslock and produces a real A.

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: I added one more shortcut line on the bottom and it works fine (F10::MsgBox try me out). Maybe the problem is that your rest of the code causes some troubles?

Comment: @cajmer: Are you sure that you get a real Esc? I added a bit more information about what the code does on my end. And no I don't have any additional lines in my script.

Comment: You're right, I didn't get correct Esc. I focused more on "other function" - my bad. Anyway, I've submitted an answer that should meet your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this code:

```
inProcess = 0

Capslock::
    Gui, 93:+Owner ; prevent display of taskbar button
    Gui, 93:Show, y-99999 NA, Enable nav-hotkeys
    inProcess = 1
    KeyWait, Capslock ; wait until the Capslock button is released
    Gui, 93:Cancel
    if (inProcess == 1){
        Send, {Esc}
    }
Return

#IfWinExist, Enable nav-hotkeys
    *c::
    Run, www.stackoverflow.com
    inProcess = 0
    return
#IfWinExist, ; end context-sensitive block
```

I've modified an answer available here: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/56428-problem-rebinding-ctrl-to-capslock-using/

Comment: I got it to work by adding `inProcess = 0` as a flag to prevent the Esc from getting send. Thanks for your help.